# Filter out all of user's entries if one of them was selected

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula that will allow you to put up to 3 values into a pool (per person) and then when one of those values is selected for use all 3 potential values are removed from the pool.

My current formula is long but fairly simple in that it takes the values from each user and adds/subtracts them based on whether they are being used.

```
=(SUMIF($I$2:$I$50, $A24, $L$2:$L$50) + SUMIF($J$2:$J$50, $A24, $L$2:$L$50) + SUMIF($K$2:$K$50, $A24, $L$2:$L$50)) - (SUMIF($A$2:$A$20, $A24, $L$2:$L$20) + SUMIF($B$2:$B$20, $A24, $L$2:$L$20) + SUMIF($C$2:$C$20, $A24, $L$2:$L$20) + SUMIF($D$2:$D$20, $A24, $L$2:$L$20) + SUMIF($E$2:$E$20, $A24, $L$2:$L$20))
```

The limiting factor here is that each user is adding a potential of 3 values to the pool but when one is selected it is only subtracting that from the pool and then leaving the other 2 which invalidates the pool as a whole.

For reference I have copied the contents over to the following sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tbL1WuaUoR8JM8cndTBiKnoaLm-UxCaddpSOJbCVmiM/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone have an idea for how to properly remove all available options from the pool rather than just the one that was selected? I have a few ideas from how to possibly make it work with code but I am trying to make it an automated formula rather than something that needs to be specifically "run" to calculate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some marker against each user to indicate whether their entries are still eligible for taking. Here is an example: column Eligible (L) is True if we haven't chosen from that user yet. Column Selected (N) is filled manually, by choosing from what is available in column Available (O). The formulas are:

For Eligible column (second row shown):

```
=and(isna(match(I2, N$2:N, 0)), isna(match(J2, N$2:N, 0)), isna(match(K2, N$2:N, 0)))
```

which says that neither I2, J2, or K2 match anything in N.

And in column O, only one array formula is needed:

```
={filter(I2:I, L2:L); filter(J2:J, L2:L); filter(K2:K, L2:L)}
```

which filters out non-eligible users and stacks the foods in one column using array notation `{}`.

```
+--------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+--+----------+------------+
|  User  | Food 1  | Food 2 |   Food 3   | Eligible  |  | Selected | Available  |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+--+----------+------------+
| User A | Chicken | Pear   | Watermelon | TRUE      |  | Grape    | Chicken    |
| User B | Garlic  | Grape  | Rice       | FALSE     |  | Beef     | Potato     |
| User C | Beef    | Corn   | Salt       | FALSE     |  |          | Pear       |
| User D | Potato  | Pepper | Orange     | TRUE      |  |          | Pepper     |
|        |         |        |            |           |  |          | Watermelon |
|        |         |        |            |           |  |          | Orange     |
+--------+---------+--------+------------+-----------+--+----------+------------+
```

Comment: Excellent explanation, I knew I would need a field to link the users to their options but I wasn't sure how to go about it.